# Is it possible to train a single input->neuron->relu->neuron->relu for input > 0.5?

Tags: pytorch, perceptron

The neural network is simply:

```
y=max(max(x*w+b,0)*v+d,0)
```

w,b is weight and bias of first neuron.
v,d is weight and bias of second neuron.

If data is for example:

```
x = tensor([[1.0], [0.9], [0.8], [0.75], [0.7], [0.6], [0.51], [0.49], [0.3], [0.25], [0.2], [0.1], [0.0]])
y = tensor([[1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0 ], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0 ], [0.0 ], [0.0], [0.0 ], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0]])
```

Then, below values fit the data:

```
w=-12
b=6
v=-12
d=1
```

Is it possible to train the network to find above values (or other possible values) ?

I tried below code (which actually works sometimes but fails most of the times):

```
l1 = nn.Linear(1, 1)
l2 = nn.Linear(1, 1)
relu1 = nn.ReLU()
relu2 = nn.ReLU()

x = tensor([[1.0], [0.9], [0.8], [0.75], [0.7], [0.6], [0.51], [0.49], [0.3], [0.25], [0.2], [0.1], [0.0]])
y = tensor([[1.0], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0 ], [1.0], [1.0], [1.0 ], [0.0 ], [0.0], [0.0 ], [0.0], [0.0], [0.0]])

lr = 0.5

for i in range(0, 100):
    out = relu2(l2(relu1(l1(x))))
    lss = F.mse_loss(out, y)
    lss.backward()

    with torch.no_grad():
        l1.weight -= l1.weight.grad * lr
        l1.bias -= l1.bias.grad * lr
        l2.weight -= l2.weight.grad * lr
        l2.bias -= l2.bias.grad * lr
        l1.zero_grad()
        relu1.zero_grad()
        l2.zero_grad()
        relu2.zero_grad()

relu2(l2(relu1(l1(x))))
```

Comment: I also tried lss=F.binary_cross_entropy(torch.sigmoid(out), y)

Comment: The main problem seems to be dying ReLUs. Exponential linear units (ELU) do help, but then cannot exactly represent the function with only 2 neurons I guess...

Comment: Yes, having only two neurons is a problem. Also, you'd probably want more data points, and you'd want to shuffle your data and initialize your random seed. What you're describing is a Heaviside function - [link]https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function. The derivative of this is going to be zero everywhere except at x = 0, which means your gradients will go to zero pretty quickly. You can see this by printing out your gradients from within the training loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do this with the line

```
target = torch.abs(torch.ceil((torch.zeros_like(x) - 0.5) - x))
```

with no need to train a neural network. If this isn't what you're looking for please clarify what the desired output looks like. thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Actually I'm trying to understand how to train neural networks and just picked up a trivial example task for it. I tried bigger networks too, more data points and other loss functions too, but I cannot make it learn this simple function consistently so I think I'm missing something in my network or training loop...

Comment: Ah, got it. I'd recommend starting with simple linear regression in that case - basically fitting a line to a set of potentially noisy data points. This can be as simple as `class LR(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
    super().__init__()
    self.linear = nn.Linear(input_size, output_size)
  def forward(self, x):
    pred = self.linear(x)
    return pred`